# No module named google.protobuf

Tags: python, installation, protocols, protocol-buffers, deep-dream

I am trying to run Google's deep dream. For some odd reason I keep getting

> ImportError: No module named google.protobuf

after trying to import protobuf. I have installed protobuf using `sudo install protobuf`. I am running python 2.7 OSX Yosemite 10.10.3.

I think it may be a deployment location issue but i cant find anything on the web about it. Currently deploying to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Comment: Did you pip install google.protobuf?

Comment: I did "pip install protobuf" but I still get ImportError: No module named google.protobuf after using "from google.protobuf import text_format" in python 2.7.6

Comment: Is there a chance you have two pythons on your computer? If you do use the pip directly from scripts folder

Comment: I think you are on to something. I do have multiple python versions. What do you mean by using the pp directly from the scripts folder?

Answer (score 37):

There is another possibility, if you are running a python 2.7.11 or other similar versions,

```
sudo pip install protobuf
```

is ok.

But if you are in a anaconda environment, you should use

```
conda install protobuf
```

Comment: What if I have compiled protobuf 2.6.0 source and the python is 3.5? I am facing an issue for importing caffe `from .proto.caffe_pb2 import TRAIN, TEST
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/caffe/proto/caffe_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.internal import enum_type_wrapper
ImportError: No module named 'google.protobuf'`.

Comment: I have exported the path in bashrc as well `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}`, and I do not know what is the reason

Comment: why do I have to do `conda install` with this particular package instead of `pip install` that works with other packages?

Comment: @S.EB I am in a similar situation with Protobuf 2.6.1, from what I gather from my testing, the compiler itself isn't backwards compatible (as in, protoc from Protobuf 3.x.x can't compile .proto files created with Protobuf 2 in mind), but the library API (including the Python interface) is backwards compatible. I was able to successfully use the latest protobuf package from pip to communicate with a device that uses an interface designed for Protobuf 2.

Comment: @S.EB Also, don't try and use the python interface that comes with Protobuf 2.6.X, it seems to be made for Python 2 and it won't work with any Python 3 scripts; I've found some posts / commit messages saying that Google added support for Python 3 in 2.6.0, but I don't think it was finished at that time, because the code seems to only support a Python version of 1 or 2 for the setup, 3 isn't accepted.

Answer (score 21):

Locating the `google` directory in the `site-packages` directory (for the proper latter directory, of course) and manually creating an (empty) `__init__.py` resolved this issue for me.

(Note that within this directory is the `protobuf` directory but my installation of Python 2.7 did not accept the new-style packages so the `__init__.py` was required, even if empty, to identify the folder as a package folder.)

...In case this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: Thanks! Great hint

Comment: saved my life! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @WormHole You're likely using Python 2.7, which requires the noted file.  Google Protobuf assumes you're using Python 3.x.  At least this is my understanding.  So, not a bug - just a Python version annoyance.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I

1. downloaded the source code, compiled and installed:

   ```
   $ ./configure
   $ make
   $ make check
   $ sudo make install`
   ```
2. for python I located its folder(python) under source code, and ran commands:

   ```
   $ python setup.py build
   $ python setup.py install'
   ```

Not sure if this could help you..

Comment: I'd like to add that for some systems step 1 is probably already done for you. You just need to do step 2. In my case I had to dowload the whole protobuf zip file and look for the python subfolder.

Comment: Wanted to add that the repository has changed to now require ./autogen.sh before you can run ./configure.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error message when I tried to use Tensor Flow. The solution was simply to **uninstall** Tensor Flow and protobuf:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall protobuf
$ sudo pip uninstall tensorflow
```

And reinstall it again: [pip installation of Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation). Currently, this is:

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only:
$ sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled:
$ sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.8.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Mac OS X, CPU only:
$ sudo easy_install --upgrade six
$ sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.8.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 3):

when I command **pip install protobuf**, I get the error:

> Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

If you have the same problem as me, you should do the following commands.

`pip install --ignore-installed six
sudo pip install protobuf`

Answer (score 2):

According to your comments, you have multiply versions of python
what could happend is that you install the package with pip of anthor python

pip is actually link to script that donwload and install your package.

two possible solutions:

1. go to $(PYTHONPATH)/Scripts and run pip from that folder that way you insure
   you use the correct pip
2. create alias to pip which points to $(PYTHONPATH)/Scripts/pip and then run pip install

how will you know it worked?
Simple if the new pip is used the package will be install successfully, otherwise the package is already installed

Answer (score 0):

I installed the protobuf with this command:

```
conda install -c anaconda protobuf=2.6.1
```

(you should check the version of protobuf)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, MacOS has the permission control.
 `sudo -H pip3 install protobuf`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to when I had a google.py file in my project files.
It is quite easy to reproduce.
main.py: `import tensorflow as tf`
google.py: `print("Protobuf error due to google.py")`

Not sure if this is a bug and where to report it.