# Python3 ImportError: No module named 'google.protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

I have compiled protobuf 2.6.0 source code in my ubuntu system, once I wanna import caffe, it is showing the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/caffe/__init__.py:30: UserWarning: Caffe datatype DOUBLE not available.
  warnings.warn("Caffe datatype DOUBLE not available.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/caffe/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .proto.caffe_pb2 import TRAIN, TEST
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/caffe/proto/caffe_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.internal import enum_type_wrapper
ImportError: No module named 'google.protobuf'
>>> 
[11]+  Stopped                 python3
```

I have exported the protobuf path in `.bashrc`
export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}`

the caffe is built by Python3. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named google.protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308812/no-module-named-google-protobuf)

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `make install` after compilation?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove and install again. If you use Conda, make sure you remove it from pip and Conda.
Here is an [issue](https://ai-pool.com/d/importerror--no-module-named-google-protobuf) opened in the community